# Existence and uniqueness of an abstract mathematical problem

Tags: logic

Suppose P is an abstract mathematical problem, an element $x$ is a solution of P if P(x) is true. The uniqueness is defined as P is unique determined if any two solution of P is equal.

Question: I have read that for the definition of uniqueness one does not require the solution exist. However, how can this be consistent as if there exists no solution, how can I check if any two solution is equal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uniqueness means:

$$\forall x,y\ \ P(x)\land P(y)\implies x=y$$

If there is no solution, both $P(x)$ and $P(y)$ are false, which makes the implication true [(vacuous truth concept)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth).

The nice thing is that the opposite:
$$\forall x,y\ \ P(x)\land P(y)\implies x\ne y$$
is also true.

In other words, anything you would say about things that do not exist is true (you could say "My car is a Ferarri", and that would be true if you don't have a car).

Answer (score 0):

Non-uniquenes of solution means that there are at least two solutions. But there is not even one. In other words:

> Suppose that $P(x)$ is true, $P(y)$ is true and $x\neq y$. Since $P$
>   has no solution, $P(x)$ is false. Contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

This general [Uniqueness Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/UniquenessTheorem.html) article is helpful.

It is stated there that

"in such cases, a uniqueness theorem is normally combined with an existence theorem"

The antiderivative of any function is unique, up to a constant. But they might not exist for a wild and crazy function.

Following is a list uniqueness theorems in the mathematical literature without a corresponding existence theorem/statement/boundary condition. I encourage anyone with some interesting examples to edit this answer and add to this (short?) list.

---

1.